# Orginal lightning cable works with only when pushing upwards - iPhone X

Tags: iphone, ios, hardware, lightning

After I have run with iPhone X with Lightning Earpods in wet and cold conditions (it was raining, about 3°-2°) and I was probably applying force on the cable just in the connector area - (the iPhone was loose in the pocket) - my original lightning cable works now only when pulling the cable up (looking at the iPhone screen). The same holds true for the Lightning Earpods.

[image: representation of me pushing the cable up]

The contacts pins of the lightning connector appear on the bottom of the port. So it makes sense that skewing a little upwards it might get contact - but it means that the pins are worn out. What are my options? Should I try to tinker with some small needle to try to pry the contacts pins up? Is it even feasible?

Is my diagnosis correct or at least probable?

PS: Interestingly enough the non-orginal lightning cable which might be a little bit thicker on the ending part - works without pushing the cable up.

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that you simply have dirt, dust or various particles blocking the Lightning port so that the cable doesn't fully insert like it is supposed to.

I would suggest trying to clean the Lighting port on the phone. Use a can of compressed air if you have that, and give it a few, short, bursts while holding the can upright.

If this doesn't work, use a gentle tool to mechanically remove the debris. For example an plastic tooth pick or similar. Do not use metal objects and a lot of force - it is key to be gentle with the connector.